# "Не()слишком" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Слитно или раздельно пишется "не()слишком" в предложении: "Стол был не()слишком разнообразным"? При слитном написании Ворд выдает ошибку - почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте *слишком* заменить на *очень*. Конечно, *не слишком* пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно,  это слово с "не" пишется  раздельно!